# Как сделать ограничение поворота объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

Как сделать ограничение на вращение? Чтобы игрок сам поворачивал объект, и было ограничение

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если на объекте имеется RigidBody2D - при достижении условия можно зафризить rotation(constaints) по той оси, которая вам нужна. Например:

```cs
// Условие не является точным! rotation - не указана ротация по оси
if (object.transform.rotation >= 90f)
{
    // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ограничить количество вращений или угол?
Второй вариант можно реализовать через метод *Mathf.Clamp()*
Ниже - ограничения по "х" оси.

```
Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * _speed;

newPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, -1.5f, 1.5f);
transform.position = newPosition;
```